# Can't complete mup setup on Dreamhost aka Meteor Up

Tags: meteor, setup-deployment, dreamhost

I'm stuck at the `mup setup`. Trying to set it up on my Dreamhost server.

Here is what I started with after running `mup setup`:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[mydomain.com] - Installing Node.js
[mydomain.com] ✘ Installing Node.js: FAILED
 -----------------------------------STDERR------------
     tty present and no askpass program specified
    Sorry, try again.
    sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
    Sorry, try again.
```

Then I installed node manually on my server, and set the mup file to `"setupNode": false`. Tried again and got that:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[mydomain.com] - Installing PhantomJS
[mydomain.com] ✘ Installing PhantomJS: FAILED
 -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------
         tty present and no askpass program specified
        Sorry, try again.
        sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
        Sorry, try again.
```

Finally, I also deactivated the PhantomJS install, tried again to run `mup setup` and got that:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[mydomain.com] - Setting up Environment
[mydomain.com] ✔ Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
[mudomain.com] - Copying MongoDB configuration
[mydomain.com] ✘ Copying MongoDB configuration: FAILED

 -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------
        Warning: Permanently added 'mydomain.com,69.163.152.69' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
        scp: /etc/mongodb.conf: Permission denied
        Killed by signal 1.
 -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 Completed TaskList: Setup (linux)
```

I am not sure what to do or try next. Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Posted the correct answer below. Appreciate if you could mark mine as correct, or suggest why it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like its a Permission problem.

Try with `sudo mup setup` or whatever name process are you running, initialize with the `sudo` keyword

From dream Host forums (admin or tutor post).

> > node.js — which is used by Meteor — causes some weird issues on our shared hosting servers that can trigger this behavior. We're aware of
> >     the issue, but, for various reasons, it's been difficult to fix.
>
> That being said, Meteor won't work on a shared hosting account anyway,
>   as it runs as a persistent server process, which isn't permitted.
>   You'd need a DreamHost VPS or dedicated server to run Meteor.

So if you don't have a dreamHost VPS or dedicated server, and you only want to deploy the app give a try to [Modulus.io](https://modulus.io), it works pretty fine with meteor, or use the meteor deploy servers, doc [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yeah, that's what I thought. But the Meteor commands happen locally. And where it gets stuck I think is remotely, on the server. I just tried to use sudo just to see anyway, and in all 3 cases and I got the same results.

Comment: do you have VPS or dedicated server on dream host?

Comment: Ah. Yes. I do have a shared server. That's what I thought the issue might be. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This answer didn't help me at all - it's more of a tip or suggestion than a working solution to the original question.

Comment: @a20 i feel so sorry that my answer didnt   help you, but atleast you get a tip, which is sorta good right? =D

Comment: @Ethaan hahah ok .. I was frustrated at not finding the answer ;) Found it and just wrote it up below.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because Sudo isn't installed on the target machine.**

On my `Debian` target machine I did `apt-get install sudo` to resolve this. 
For a `RedHat flavor (Centos etc)` target machine you might do `yum install sudo` etc.

However mup is supported for Ubuntu only so it's very likely to run into issues with other flavors. You might want to stick with Ubuntu target machines to avoid headaches like these.